# How to access private member variables in a dynamic array of objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, pointers

I have two classes. Class `WorldList` holds a  a pointer to a dynamic array of `WordOccurence` objects:

```
class WordOccurrence {
public:
{...member functions...}
private:
    string word_;
    int num_;
};

class WordList{
public:
WordList(WordList&);
{...member functions...}
private:
    WordOccurrence *wordArray_; 

    int size_;
};
```

Here's my problem: I'm getting an error in my copy constructor when I try to access the `WordOccurence` variables. My copy constructor looks like this:

```
WordList::WordList(WordList &rhs){
    size_ = rhs.size_;
    wordArray_ = new WordOccurrence[rhs.size_];
    for(int i = 0; i < rhs.size_; ++i){
        wordArray_[i]->word_ = rhs.wordArray_[i]->getWord();
        wordArray_[i]->num_ = rhs.wordArray_[i]->getNum();
    }
}
```

The errors I'm getting say:

> error: member reference type 'WordOccurrence' is not a pointer; did
>   you mean to use '.'?
>
> error: 'word_' is a private member of 'WordOccurrence'

and repeated for `num_ variable`.

Can anyone shed some light on what I might be missing here? I thought that it was ok to access private member variables through a pointer to that specific object, is that not the idea behind the arrow operator?

Comment: Sorry, this is in c++

Comment: Why would it be ok to access private members through pointers? That would make `private` completely useless. And the first error message even tells you exactly what you need to change, what's unclear about it?

Comment: Because when we want to access members of a class through a pointer, we want to use the arrow operator, no?

Comment: `rhs.wordArray_[i]` is not a pointer, it's a `WordOccurrence`. The arrow operator has no more privileges than the "dot" operator.

Comment: Ok I think I understand that, thanks. So is there no way to assign those variables from the value of the rhs object variables without making a separate mutator function?

Answer (score 0):

Your `wordArray_` is defined as a pointer to a `WordOccurrence`:

```
    WordOccurrence *wordArray_
```

So the type of `wordArray_[i]` refers to a `WordOccurrence` object.  And to access members of an object, you should use `.`  and not `->`.

The problem that you still have, is that you try to set directly the members of the new occurrences:

```
    wordArray_[i].word_ = rhs.wordArray_[i].getWord();
    wordArray_[i].num_ = rhs.wordArray_[i].getNum();
```

Now `getWord()` and `getNum()` are public, but `word_` and `num_` are private to WordOccurence and so invisible to `WordList`.

The easy dirty way, would be to make Wordlist a friend of WordOccurence:

```
class WordOccurence {
    ...
    friend class WordList; 
};
```

A much cleaner way, would be to rely on a copy constructor of `WordOccurences`:

```
WordList::WordList(WordList &rhs){
    size_ = rhs.size_;
    wordArray_ = new WordOccurrence[rhs.size_];
    for(int i = 0; i < rhs.size_; ++i){
        wordArray_[i] = rhs.wordArray_[i]; 
    }
}
```

Now, an even better way would be to define `wordArray_` as `vector<WordOccurence>` instead of an array: you'd then no longer have to worry about its copy.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up adding mutator functions to WordOccurrence so I could just invoke those functions to initialize the variables.

Comment: i would consider relying on a copy ctor, as mentioned in the answer. If you ever decide on changing the structure of `WordOccurence` it can lead to a headache. Highly recommend providing that class with a copy ctor.